# Jade each iteration modulus for responsive Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, pug, twitter-bootstrap-3

Pretty new to Jade and the whole "indentation matters" bit is nice, but it has its downsides.

I'm trying to iterate over an object to spit out a responsive Twitter Bootstrap grid. Normally, in the traditional HTML world, I'd use modulus to end my current `row` by closing my `</div>`, but I can't figure out how to make this work in the Jade world.

#### I tried this:

```
  each val, index in team

      if index % 3 == 0
         div.row(style="border: solid 1px")

     .col-md-2.thumbnail
        img.img-responsive(src=val.image)
        .caption.text-center
           h4
            =val.name
```

But since `.col` isn't properly indented, it throws an error.

In short, I want three items per row, each wrapped in a `div.row`

Worth noting this is the [new Bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/) syntax, but help/suggestions in the 2.3 syntax is perfectly fine.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You either have to prepare your data structure to be a list of lists (with 3 entries each), or use inline raw HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, try this.

```
each val, index in team
    if (index % 3 == 0)
        div.row(style="border: solid 1px")
            each val2, index2 in team.slice(index, index+3)
                .col-md-2.thumbnail
                    img.img-responsive(src=team[index+index2].image)
                    .caption.text-center
                        h4
                            =team[index+index2].name
```

Comment: This is the answer, but your code has a typo/error. I had to fix `if((index # 3) == 0)` to `if (index % 3 == 0)` in order for it to work.

Comment: Worked great for me. Thanks!